# Multiple MySQL count in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mariadb

I have at the moment multiple queries that 1 would like to collect into one, they are identical only the date range is changing :

**Query 1 :**

```
SELECT COUNT(simp_posts.ID)
FROM simp_posts
INNER JOIN simp_postmeta
ON ( simp_posts.ID = simp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value = '0' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-08-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-08-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-pending-cancel'))
```

**Query 2 :**

```
SELECT COUNT(simp_posts.ID)
FROM simp_posts
INNER JOIN simp_postmeta
ON ( simp_posts.ID = simp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value = '0' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-09-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-09-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-pending-cancel'))
```

**Query 3 :**

```
SELECT COUNT(simp_posts.ID)
FROM simp_posts
INNER JOIN simp_postmeta
ON ( simp_posts.ID = simp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value = '0' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-active'))
OR ( ( simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:33:51' AND simp_posts.post_status = 'wc-pending-cancel'))
```

I would like these query to be combined into one and have a result be 3 rows with the result of each count in one.
For example I would get :
182
183
194

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can simplify the answer by using `SUM()` with booleans.

Your logic is complicated.  I think it reduces to:

```
SELECT SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-09-01 23:33:51'),
       SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:33:51'),
SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:33:51')
FROM simp_posts p INNER JOIN
     simp_postmeta pm
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND
      p.post_status IN ('wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel')
```

Comment: Thank you it's perfect ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have the common conditions in `where` and aggregate conditionally on the date ranges. 
Note what @Tim mentions in the comments. If the counts have to be mutually exclusive include a range of `meta_value` in the `case` expression.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-08-01 23:33:51' 
                  THEN simp_posts.ID END)
,COUNT(CASE WHEN simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-09-01 23:33:51' 
            THEN simp_posts.ID END)
,COUNT(CASE WHEN simp_postmeta.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:33:51' 
            THEN simp_posts.ID END)
FROM simp_posts
INNER JOIN simp_postmeta ON simp_posts.ID = simp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE simp_postmeta.meta_key = '_schedule_end' 
AND simp_posts.post_status IN ('wc-active','wc-pending-cancel')
```

Comment: This is literally the right answer, but I think your date ranges will double count, e.g. `2018-09-02` would be counted by two count statements, and the OP may not actually intend this.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this doesnt give me the right count when I try it. But nevermind, the answer of Gordon, below does :) Thank you